# Navigation at left side side in master page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I am developing ASP.NET Web forms site and in master page there are two navigation one is usual horizontal and other is Left side navigation like in most of configuration sites like php my admin. or tutorial point site like left navigation. I added vertical navigation in master page but the content in other pages coming below that navigation.
[Here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/z4Q2r) is what is have refered.

in master page

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu3</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu5</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
 <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
</ul>
 </div
```

in other page just sample

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h2>Left side Navigation bar (Fixed)</h2>

<p>Left side Navigation</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide images or code

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your css? Where is your html? Do you expect code from SO users when you didn't provide a sample? Update your question pls

Comment: just did. Please check. one is from master page and other from normal pages

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0mn3gtfy/2/)

You are missing the correct css to align things where they need to go.  You should include a css file in the head of your master page, if you haven't already done so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

Place all your css in there.